# Проверка переполнения в SmartObjectAllocator из книги Alexandrescu "Modern C++ Design"

Tags: c++

При изучении аллокатора Alexandrescu для маленьких объектов, наткнулся на следующую проверку переполнения. Это фрагмент функции с проверкой, сама функция инициализирует кусок памяти-Chunk, который делится на блоки указанного размера и их кол-ва)

```
bool Chunk::Init( std::size_t blockSize, unsigned char blocks )
{
...
    // Overflow check
    const std::size_t allocSize = blockSize * blocks;
    assert( allocSize / blockSize == blocks);
...
}
```

Не могу понять как может(и в каких случаях) сработать этот ассерт, ведь мы получили allocSize как произведение blockSize и blocks, так каким образом allocSize / blockSize не может быть равным blocks? Прошу пояснить в чем суть данной проверки

Comment: В случае, когда в `blockSize * blocks` произойдет переполнение.

Comment: Это проверка *арифметического переполнения* при умножении.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

При умножении целых чисел и потом его целочисленном делении происходит математически тот-же результат, а при уменьшении на минимальное значение результат будет меньше.

```
[ A * B / B ] == A
[ ( ( A * B ) - 1 ) / B ] < A
```

Переполнение, это когда результат умножения не может поместиться на границы значений типа `size_t`. Если умножение `blockSize * blocks` не может поместиться в тип `size_t`, то `allocSize` будет строго меньше `blockSize * blocks`. А значит при делении на `blockSize` результат будет строго меньше `blocks`.

```
ЕСЛИ : allocSize < blockSize * blocks
ТО   : [ allocSize / blockSize ] < blocks
```

*В современных компиляторах этот приём уже может не работать. Оптимизация компилятора может предположить, что результат всегда верный. А стандарт говорит, что при умножении с переполнением компилятор может сам делать неопределённое исполнение.*